# How to run 'runas` program in Windows as administrator without password

Tags: windows, runas

I have a Python code that finally generates a file and it should automatically run that file as admin. I did search and found that I should use `runas` program, but it requires admin password.

Since I have not set any administrator password, so it should not ask for password in order to work.

The script is `route add -p IP` to change routing table.

There are multiple PCs in the office and all PCs have one user like `saeed`, `david`, etc. and `administrator` of course which has not been used yet.

The command I use is the following that asks for admin password:

```
C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop> Runas /profile /user:administrator ips.cmd
Enter the password for administrator:
Attempting to start new-ips.cmd as user "DESKTOP-9PR0R3P\administrator" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - new-ips.cmd
1326: The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Is that possible to run `run as` passwordless?

I should mention that if with my current PC, I right click on `ips.cmd` and Run As Administrator, it does not prompt any password and runs the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this command works for me:

```
powershell.exe "Start-Process powershell -verb runAs"
```